# Collaboration with Java IDE

Tags: java, css, jsp, intellij-idea

We need to be able to share the viewing and editing of a Java coding project that was started in Intellij.

We need to be able to start by giving someone view-only access to a single file, and eventually allow them to see and edit other pieces.

Intellij does not appear to support this scenario directly, so we tested doing it in these two tools.

The Visual Studio Community Edition IDE says that it supports collaboration on the version comparison page but doesn't appear to support Java
vs_community__1095676675.1612398125.exe
blob:https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/bfa14bfc-7573-43d5-81a8-eba84694b332

The VSCode IDE supports Java but not collaboration.
VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.54.3.exe
https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8/VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.54.3.exe

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The two suggestions that were made both work to some extent. Code With Me and GitLive both seem to do the trick, although GitLive seems more integrated with Git which seems like a potentially better choice. The problem of not allowing any single person to view more than what they have been given to work on is still a problem. Is there any way around this with GitLive or any other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share code files, use a source code versioning management tool such as [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) or [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git). IntelliJ supports several such tools.

If you want to collaborate live with another programmer within IntelliJ, use the new *Code With Me* tool.

## *Code With Me* for IntelliJ

The JetBrains company has released a new plugin for their IntelliJ IDE: *Code With Me*.

> Code With Me is a new collaborative development and pair programming service. It enables you to share the currently opened project in your IDE with others, and work on it together in real time.

This product:

> … enables you to share an open project in your IDE with your distributed team. This allows them to quickly access your code, so they can help you investigate issues, review, and work on your code together with you in real time. And all this can be done while still enjoying the full benefits of the code autocompletion, smart navigation, refactoring, debugging suite, and built-in terminal available in your JetBrains IDE.

The guest invited to a work session need not even have IntelliJ installed. No IDE is required to connect as a guest, you only need an invitation link. For guests, only a lightweight client application is downloaded.

*Code With Me* also provides audio or video calls between participants.

See the [product page](https://www.jetbrains.com/code-with-me/), their [*Getting Started* guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-with-me.html), and [FAQ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/faq-about-code-with-me.html). See [their blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2020/09/28/code-with-me-eap/) explaining the early-access version. The company likely published video demonstrations on [their YouTube.com channel](https://www.youtube.com/@JetBrainsTV). [Search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Code%20With%20Me%22%20jetbrains&t=osx&ia=web) to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go with this. The usual 'kneejerk' reaction to the underlying idea (I want to 'remote' pair program! – I assume that is what you want here; possibly replace 'pair program' with 'coach' or 'code review') is to set up an editor such that it is a server/client getup where multiple humans can connect to the 'server', and they all see the same editor. Think 'Google Docs', but in a code editor.

There are technologies out there that accomplish this. Eclipse has plugins such as Saros, and for intellij there's something like [GitLive](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11955-gitlive).

There is a problem, though. It *sounds* like collaborative edits fulfils your needs to remote-pair-program, remote-coach, etc, **but that usually does not actually work very well**. Programming involves more than an IDE. For example, a ton of dev involves writing web services stuff, and generally the IDE does not contain a full fledged browser, and definitely does not contain a browser-based debugging tool (right click: Inspect Element - that kinda debugging). Collaboration also involves code review, and often it can be convenient for a team to temporarily 'split off' - where the 2 people working in pairs stop sharing a single editor and each work on their own thing. Nobody likes just staring idly at their screen whilst a supervisor types up some notes in the git commit.

Thus, you may want to think about how people actually program and how one would come up with a collaborative setup that lets you actually collaborate whilst remaining practical, and you get to a different answer:

**Source-control based collaboration with optional voice/video calling + full screen sharing.**

There are a *ton* of tools out there to do collaboration based on source control, in particular, git-based source control. For example, a workflow where somebody makes a commit (which lets the creator of the work bundle up a change into a sane atomic unit, which usually is not as simple as 'all the changes made to a single file', and lets them add a comment about what they did and why they did that can be as long a you want), which then goes into a review queue, and then a code reviewer can automatically 'pick up' these changes into their local copy of the repo, review it, and commit this, and even 'flag' whether another cycle is required (where the comments and edits go back to the original creator), or not - with each person doing a review able to add a signature. Then a CI system automatically updates (and runs the test suite on) the production version by pulling in all commits that have gathered sufficient signatures. Any commit that isn't 'signed off' is simply not included by the CI tooling.

I would suggest you use such a system, and in the rare cases where true as-you-type pair programming is required for direct coaching for example, just use generic screen sharing tools – this also solves the problem when you need to switch to e.g. the browser to do some javascript debugging.

This also lets the 'someone' in your question have the ability to eventually see and edit lots of files, independent of their supervisor or however the relationship is defined: They just have all those files on their disk, pulled via git. They can edit whatever they want, in whatever fashion they like, and mess around and have open bugs they don't know how to solve, without messing with other folks' workflow: They bundle their work up in a commit which others can then accept when and only when they are ready to do so.

Source control in general does 90% of what is usually desired for 'collaborative programming': If Jane has done a bunch of work but has some questions about it, then Jane (who is of course working in her own branch for this update) can simply push it striaght to Aki's system, where Aki can review the changes, run it if need be, even make changes - and they'll be using a channel that is appropriate for in-depth discussion and swapping of ideas and experience: A voice or even video call, running whilst both of them are staring at the relevant source code, in their own system, as configured in the way they prefer.

Note that trying to solve the problem of personal preferences by dictating the system being used in exacting fashion (everybody must use this edition of intellij at this version with these plugins and these visual settings!) is not very inclusive: Some folks have accessibility needs which are mutually exclusive.

That may explain a significant chunk of why the 'use git to collaborate, and just share a screen and start a (video) call if needed' is so much more popular than a 'lets all work on a single server-based IDE, google-docs style' model.

But, if you really wanna go for it, give GitLive a try.

Answer (score 1):

CodeTogether supports remote pair programming in IntelliJ, VS Code, Eclipse, and all the IDEs based on them.

You can restrict what files are shared as well as read/write access per participant. You can also work on the same file with a shared cursor, individual cursors, or on different files, all simultaneously with up to 32 people. CodeTogether is available in the marketplace of whatever IDE you use. More info is at CodeTogether.com

Disclaimer: I’m an employee of Genuitec and CodeTogether is our product. However, I’m only mentioning it here because it seems to address this poster’s requirements.